# Seeding 300mb Sqlite database for react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sqlite, ionic-react

**Problem**

I have a large sqlite db (~300mb) and I want to use it to seed my application on load and store to the filesystem to use sqlite queries. For context, it is a language dictionary application.

I have looked around, and I haven't found a solution that is applicable to my situation. Ideally, I understand that I can use the `importFromJson` function from the `@capacitor-community/sqlite"` plugin.

The issue with this is, the file seems to be too large + not being able to find applicable examples to implement properly since this is all new to me.

I am following this example : https://github.com/jepiqueau/react-sqlite-app-starter/blob/02809174e3b5bb355e506ed3bf20e1a92c74f860/src/pages/Tab1.tsx#L22

`const retImport: any = await sqlite.importFromJson(JSON.stringify(jsonImport));`

this line here, If I stringify my data, I am sure this is not going to work since the data would consume too many resources.

**Expected Results**

I want to be able to import large (~300mb) sqlite OR JSON files to seed my react ionic database to use with Sqlite.

Is there a way I can stream the json file, upload it in chunks? I am aware how to do with `fs` but I don't know to do with react native + ionic + @capacitor-community/sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

ok! So I solved this for importing a .sqlite db dump for react ionic native using that capacitor sqlite community plugin.

#### How to import and use a .sqlite file

1. Export your file from your `sqlite3` database
2. copy that file into your `public/assets/databases` folder as `<name>.db`. **Make sure to change the extension to `.db`** AND also add the definition in your `databases.json` file in the same directory

   {
   "databaseList": [
   "test_db.db"
   ]
   }
3. Before you connect to the db by name, use the function `await sqlite.copyFromAssets();` after importing `import { sqlite, existingConn } from '../App';` from the `App.tsx` file as mentioned in the boiler plate I linked before. Please refer to the `App.tsx + Index.tsx` files.
4. Create the connection and Connect to the db

```
  const db = await sqlite.createConnection("<db_name>", false, "no-encryption", 1);
  await db.open();
```

5. Then, you should be able to query this database assuming you know the names of the tables you're querying.

```
let values = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM <table_name> LIMIT 10;`)
```